# Problem with custom function when I go back with the browser

Tags: functions, actions

I have a custom function inside `functions.php` to show the typical social media buttons for each post listed (last entries, categories and tags pages):

```
//Social Media
function showSocialButtons() { ?>
    <div class="social-buttons">
        <div class="twitter">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-text="<?php the_title() ?>" data-lang="es" data-count="vertical" data-via="twitterUser"></a>
        </div>&nbsp;
        <div class="facebook"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php the_permalink() ?>&amp;layout=box_count&amp;action=like&amp;share=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;locale=es_ES" style="height:87px; width:74px"></iframe></div>
        <div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ></div>
    </div>

<?php
}

add_action('show_social_buttons','showSocialButtons');
```

Then, in the template file, inside the loop:

```
<?php do_action( 'show_social_buttons' ); ?>
```

This is working right, but when I go back to the posts list. E.g. I'm in the home page with a list of the last posts. I click on one post, and then, I go back to the home page. If I do that, the social buttons are shown, but not always in the correct post, I mean, e.g. the second post contains the first post social buttons and vice versa. Any idea of what can be causing this issue?

Comment: You can check it at http://www.nosabesnada.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I cannot replicate your problem.

I'm uncertain as to why it is going wrong as I cannot see the loop that is being used, but a way that you could probably ensure it works is to adjust your function to accept a $post input:

```
//Social Media
function showSocialButtons( $post = null ) { 
    if( ! $post ){
        global $post;
    }
    //The output
}
```

You will need to change your functions to reflect this though. For example:

```
the_title();
```

would become

```
echo get_the_title( $post->ID );
```

or simply

```
echo $post->post_title;
```

Furthermore, it's unlikely it's what's causing the trouble but I don't think you're using action hooks for their intended purpose. Actions in WP should be considered similar to events in javascript (but with synchronocity maintained). How you're currently using it is a long-winded route to something the same as an argument-free function call.

In general, actions should be placed inside functions or in an important part of the script so that multiple functions can be attached to that occasion:

```
function showSocialMediaButtons(){
    //Some code here
    do_action( 'social_media_buttons_shown' );
}
```

combined with:

```
 add_action( 'social_media_buttons_shown', 'myFuncToDoAfterEveryShowingOfSocialMediaButtons' );
```

will mean that everytime

```
 showSocialMediaButtons();
```

is called,

```
 myFuncToDoAfterEveryShowingOfSocialMediaButtons();
```

will be called immediately after.

Anyway, in your situation, rather than using

```
//functions.php
add_action( 'show_social_buttons', 'showSocialButtons' );
```

and

```
//template.php
do_action( 'show_social_buttons' );
```

Just use

```
//template.php
showSocialButtons();
```

or, if you've changed the function to use the $post variable as an argument as I suggested above:

```
//template.php
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $q->have_posts() ): $q->next_post(); //or however you've done your loop
    .
    .
    .
    showSocialButtons( $q->post ); //or whatever is referencing the post at this time.
    .
    .
    .
endwhile;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried not using the `do_action` (just the function included directly on the templates), but I'me getting the same result. The other option (using WP_Query) would make me change all templates almost from the top to the bottom, and also custom functions, ... and anyway, I think this wouldn't change anything.

Comment: The WP_Query isn't the important part of it. If you've used get_posts or whatever, that's fine too. The key thing I was thinking that my resolve any erratic behaviour was to pass the WP_Post object directly to your function to avoid any trouble with the `global $post` being set incorrectly or unexpectedly differently at that point in time.

Comment: Even using `showSocialButtons(get_post());` when I go back with the browser I'm getting the buttons unsorted. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: `get_post()` uses `global $post` if no id parameter is given. Would it be possible for you to put up the method you're using for looping through posts?

Comment: Actually, as it's a browser-centric problem (as in involving the back button) and I can't replicate the issue at my end, it might well be a simple caching of javascript issue. Have you tried emptying your cache or using dev-tools to ensure cache refresh each page load?

Comment: Probably. If I reload the page the buttons are correctly displayed. But the previous page is the same page displayed before, so why should the cache cause this issue?

Comment: Depending on the browser, it may cache the page and all its elements as a point in its history and a later instance of the same page may be cached separately in the history (as if two different pages). I know that chrome has a tendency to do this (and can persist in caching even when told not to).